Spring cache prompt could not find cacheProperties
application.yml
spring:
    cache:
        type: redis
        redis:
            cache-null-values: true
            time-to-live: 3600000

CacheConfigure.java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class CacheConfigure {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory, CacheProperties cacheProperties) {
        Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> initialCacheConfiguration = new HashMap<>(8);
        initialCacheConfiguration.put(CacheConstant.ONE_HOUR_CACHE, redisCacheConfiguration(cacheProperties).entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1)));
        initialCacheConfiguration.put(CacheConstant.TWO_HOUR_CACHE, redisCacheConfiguration(cacheProperties).entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(2)));
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration(cacheProperties))
                .withInitialCacheConfigurations(initialCacheConfiguration).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration(CacheProperties cacheProperties) {
        RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .computePrefixWith(name -> name + ":")
                .serializeKeysWith(
                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                                new StringRedisSerializer()))
                .serializeValuesWith(
                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                                new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
        CacheProperties.Redis redisProperties = cacheProperties.getRedis();
        if (redisProperties.getTimeToLive() != null) {
            config = config.entryTtl(redisProperties.getTimeToLive());
        }
        if (redisProperties.getKeyPrefix() != null) {
            config = config.prefixCacheNameWith(redisProperties.getKeyPrefix());
        }
        if (!redisProperties.isCacheNullValues()) {
            config = config.disableCachingNullValues();
        }
        if (!redisProperties.isUseKeyPrefix()) {
            config = config.disableKeyPrefix();
        }
        return config;
    }

The above code starts the project with a hint

Description:
A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties' in your configuration.

But if I don't configure CacheManage, I won't make a mistake.
